# D3.js Scatterplot with symbols

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I am trying to plot 60 points: 30 upward-pointing equilateral triangles and 30 crosses. Each symbol's X and Y coordinates is a random value between 0 and 100 inclusively which should be independently computed.

The size of symbol will be a value between 5 and 50 mapped to the domain of X values to the range of [5,50]. 
All objects with size greater than the average size of all scatterplot objects should be colored blue and all other objects should be colored green.
The plot must have visible X and Y axes that scale according to the generated objects. The ticks on these axes should adjust automatically based on the randomly generated scatterplot objects.

I have updated my code but could not figure out why my symbols are not showing properly.

```
function getRandomInt(min, max)         {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;       }
    var data_tri = [], data_crs =[]

    for (var i=0; i<30; i++)
        {
            data_tri.push([getRandomInt(0,100),getRandomInt(0,100)]);
            data_crs.push([getRandomInt(0,100),getRandomInt(0,100)]);
        }


    var margin = {top: 20, right: 15, bottom: 60, left: 60}
      , width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right
      , height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([0, d3.max(data_tri, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
              .range([ 0, width]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([0, d3.max(data_crs, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
              .range([ height, 0 ]);

    var sizeMax = d3.max([d3.max(data_crs, function(d) { return d[0];}), d3.max(data_tri, function(d) { return d[0];})])

    var sizeScale = d3.scale.linear()
              .domain([0, sizeMax])
              .range([ 5, 50 ]);

    var colorScale = d3.mean([d3.mean(data_crs, function(d) { return d[0];}), d3.mean(data_tri, function(d) { return d[0];})])

    function symbolcolor(x)
    {
        if (x > colorScale){
            return "blue";
        }
        else {
            return "green";
        }
    }

    var chart = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg:svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr('class', 'chart')
    .attr('id', 'svg_chart')


    var main = chart.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('class', 'main')   

    var xAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient('bottom');

    main.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .attr('class', 'main axis date')
    .call(xAxis1);

    var yAxis1 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient('left');

    main.append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)')
    .attr('class', 'main axis date')
    .call(yAxis1);


    var g = main.append("svg:g");

    g.selectAll("path")
            .data(data_tri)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol('cross').size(function(d){ return sizeScale(d[0]);}))
            .style("fill", function(d){ return symbolcolor(d[0]) ;})
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+xScale(d[0])+","+yScale(d[1])+")"; });

    g.selectAll("null")
            .data(data_crs)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type('triangle-up').size(function(d){ return sizeScale(d[0]);}))
            .style("fill", function(d){ return symbolcolor(d[0]) ;})
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+xScale(d[0])+","+yScale(d[1])+")"; });
```

Comment: Each of your data arrays has two values per item. Which are you trying to represent in your scatterplot?

Comment: data_tri contains x,y position for triangles and data_crs contains x,y position for crosses.I want to show both crosses and triangles on the scatterplot

Comment: You're setting the size of your symbols with `.size(function(d){ return scale(d); })` -- what is that supposed to do?

Comment: Each object’s size ia a value between 5 and 50 inclusively. I am using a linear scale for the size, to map the domain of X values to the range of [5,50]. I have written a scale function var scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([d3.min(data_tri,function(d){return d.x;}), d3.max(data_tri,function(d){return d.x;})])
        .range([5,50]);

Comment: Where in your data is that value stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having with the path errors is due to the lines like this:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data_tri)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up").size(function(d){ return scale(d); }))
```

You're calculating the size using a function that takes the argument `d`, which I presume is supposed to be the data from each item in `data_tri` or `data_crs`, but `d` is undefined. I think you wanted to do this:

```
.attr("d", function(d){
    // d is now each datum
})
```

However, if you look at each `d` item, it is an array, so this code:

```
.size(function(d){ return scale(d); })
```

will throw an error because the input to `scale(x)` should not be an array. I can't see where in your datasets you have specified the value that should be scaled, so I can't suggest a fix for that. I'm going to omit that bit completely, and just set the type of shape for each set of points:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data_tri)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up")() )
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data_crs)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("cross")() )
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
```

The next problem is that your data items don't have `d.x` and `d.y`, they are two-item arrays, so your transform function is returning `translate(undefined, undefined)`. Assuming that your arrays are in the form `[x, y]`, the transform function should be

```
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d[0] + "," + d[1] + ")"; });
```

The last two statements are thus:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data_tri)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("triangle-up")() )
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d[0] + "," + d[1] + ")"; });

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data_crs)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "point")
  .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type("cross")() )
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d[0] + "," + d[1] + ")"; });
```

You should now find that you are getting data points showing up on your chart, and you can start working out how to scale and colour your chart effectively.

Comment: Thank You!! I have updated my code but there is some issue with symbols crosses are not appearing it is only the circles